# How to grouping labels column chart on legend in highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

hai im very confused for grouping labels highcharts , please give me example for grouping highchart i give you this picture hope it's clear thanks
[this pictures highcharts for group by legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrLjb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use separate series with specified x values and category x-axis type with applied repeated breaks. Example:

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: [...],
        breaks: [{
            breakSize: 0.4,
            from: 1.5,
            to: 2.5,
            repeat: 3
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [0, 80],
            [1, 75]
        ]
    }, {
        data: [
            [3, 80],
            [4, 75]
        ]
    }, {
        data: [
            [6, 80],
            [7, 75]
        ]
    }, {
        data: [
            [9, 80],
            [10, 75]
        ]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d2tkfs09/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks

Comment: thanks man its work,and i want to ask you if i want to dynamic data categories any suggest
this example i have same label but in charts is different i give you demo i hope is clear[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ariyan1919/mo2j0gkh/16/)

Comment: Hi @riyan193, You need to add an empty category after every two points. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1zqcm0so/

Comment: hi @ppotaczek thank you very munch man is work for my web